# How are bots discovering my Azure subdomain?

Tags: azure, security, bots

I have an API hosted on Azure.  Let's call it myapi.azurewebsites.net.  The subdomain myapi has not been shared publicly, nor have any of its endpoints.  However, I am seeing traffic from Amazon Web Services and Digital Ocean hitting a specific endpoint of the format https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/widgets/version.

How is this endpoint being discovered?  The API is only being used internally in my organization by a very small dev team.  So there are no apps or websites out there that someone could be scanning traffic for to discover the endpoint URL.

Comment: For the Amazon IPs, I discovered the UserAgent was "Slackbot-LinkExpanding", so some of these were from team members pasting the URL into Slack, and Slack was attempting to expand the link by visiting the URL.  Still wondering what is causing the Digital Ocean visits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Datacenter ranges are [published](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) (as are AWS, GCP and other public cloud ranges).  Adversaries know these ranges and are constantly probing them.  There are a couple things you can do to mitigate.  The cheapest ways to limit access while testing is to enable Azure [AD auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) for your web app.  You can also implement [IP restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) in your Web app.  More costly options include to put your web app behind an [App Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app) with WAF or create an [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) where you can limit access via a Network Security Group (NSG).